# HorizontalScrollView fill with repeatable image

Tags: android, repeat, horizontalscrollview, tile, bitmapdrawable

I have a HorizontalScrollview and I want to have a repeatable image, so I can scroll infinite to left or right. This is my XML code

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_scroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

and this is my Java code

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview_scroll);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scroll);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    bitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

However, this code displays the image only once and does not repeat.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The Same image you want to repeat..? you can consider **RecycleView** too

Comment: Can you show how?

Comment: In recycle view if you set the layout manager as horizontal like this **mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));** it will work same as Horizontal Scroll view, benifit of this is we can reuse the items.